# gcc inline assembly: how to insert symbol for table address as immediate value

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, inline-assembly

I am trying to implement AES in gcc inline assembly on ARM Cortex M4. AES has many lookups into constant tables. I cannot afford to dedicate a *register* for the base address of each and every constant table, as there are *four* of them. How can I get GCC to insert a linker symbol for the *immediate value* corresponding to a table base address?

Of course, assume we've told the linker to allocate the table within a range and/or alignment that is representable by an immediate value.

As shown below, I tried `"m"` (memory) but it doesn't seem to work. In fact all `"m"` seems to do is allocate a register that is preloaded from some data relative to PC, which is exactly the sort of silliness I'm trying to avoid by writing assembly myself in the first place.

```
// C model (from openssl)
const int Te0[256] = { ... };
const int Te1[256] = { ... };
const int Te2[256] = { ... };
const int Te3[256] = { ... };
s0 =
  Te0[(t0 >> 24)       ] ^
  Te1[(t1 >> 16) & 0xff] ^
  Te2[(t2 >>  8) & 0xff] ^
  Te3[(t3      ) & 0xff] ^
  rk[0];


// asm implementation
mask = 0x3fc;
__asm("and %[z0], %[mask], %[t0], lsr 22 \n"
  "ldr %[z3], [%[rk], #0] \n"           // z3 = rk[0]

  "ldr %[z0], [%[z0], #0x200] \n"       // z0 = Te0[(t0 >> 24)       ]
  // "ldr %[z0], [%[z0], %[Te0]] \n"    // z0 = Te0[(t0 >> 24)       ]
  // ***** Why doesn't this work? *****
  // Tried binding with:
  //   [Te0] "m" (Te0)
  // Result:
  //   Error: cannot represent T32_OFFSET_IMM relocation in this object file format
  //
  // (same result with "#%[Teo]")

  "and %[z1], %[mask], %[t1], lsr 14 \n"
  "eor %[z0], %[z3] \n"                 // z0 ^= z3
  "ldr %[z1], [%[z1], #0x600] \n"       // z1 = Te1[(t1 >> 16) & 0xff]
  "and %[z2], %[mask], %[t2], lsr  6 \n"
  "ldr %[z2], [%[z2], #0xa00] \n"       // z2 = Te1[(t2 >> 16) & 0xff]
  "eor %[z0], %[z1] \n"                 // z0 ^= z1
  "and %[z3], %[mask], %[t3], lsl  2 \n"
  "ldr %[z3], [%[z3], #0xe00] \n"       // z3 = Te1[(t3 >> 16) & 0xff]
  "eor %[z0], %[z2] \n"                 // z0 ^= z2
  "eor %[z0], %[z3] \n"                 // z0 ^= z3
  :
  [z0] "=&r" (z0),
  [z1] "=&r" (z1),
  [z2] "=&r" (z2),
  [z3] "=&r" (z3)
  :
  [mask] "r" (mask),
  [t0]   "r" (t0),
  [t1]   "r" (t1),
  [t2]   "r" (t2),
  [t3]   "r" (t3),
  [rk]   "r" (rk),

  [Te0] "m" (Te0)
  );

// check the result
assert(s0 == z0);
```

The code works just fine if I pin the tables to absolute addresses and type the addresses directly in the code... But this is 2023. We use symbols in  code. How is it done in GCC?

**Update**

It was suggested to try the non-inline assembler. Here is a simple example:

```
# file test.s
# compile with arm-gcc -c test.s
#
# arm-gcc (GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 9-2020-q2-update) 9.3.1 20200408 (release)


.global Te0

    ldr r0, =Te0
    ldr r0, [r1, r0]
    # Works, but wastes a register (if first instruction is done offline)
    # or adds a load instruction (otherwise)
    
    ldr r0, [r1, #Te0]
    # Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up

    ldr r0, [r1, #=Te0]
    # Error: bad expression -- `ldr r0,[r1,#=Te0]'
```

Comment: How is `Te0` declared? And what is the precise error message?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that others can compile and execute on their own.  In my experience, inline assembly is not the right tool for this kind of task.  Either write completely in C or completely in assembly.  That removes many uncertainties from the equation.

Comment: The compiler can not create such an instruction because the value is not known until link time and there is no relocation type that would allow this. You can see doing it in asm like `ldr r0, [r0, #table]` won't work either.

Comment: I think the flip side of this is "it's the year 2023 and very few people write programs that fit in 4KiB of memory".  `ldr r0, [r1, #imm]` only takes a 12-bit immediate, so this only works if you can put these tables in the low 4K of memory.  And typically you assume that labels could be anywhere in the program, so the only way you could reliably use a label would be if you had a memory model where the entire program was less than 4K.  In fact, if you are using null pointer protection, then low addresses in particular will be unusable.

Comment: The immediate in the load instruction is meant as an index, not as a base, so you are already "abusing" this instruction.  It's not too surprising that tools don't provide a way to help you do it.

Comment: @Nate Good point about the immediate range (this particular one doesn't have a shift). However, for something as performance-critical as AES, one might be willing to put its tables in the bottom 4KB of the memory map.

Comment: @Nate If the immediate is supposed to be used as the base, then where does the base come from? I couldn't figure out how to do it without adding either more instructions or dedicating more registers. Nor could GCC. And every single register is already used. (The AES state itself is 8 registers, not counting pointers and temporaries. Cortex M4 only has 16 registers)

Comment: @TonyK I've updated the comment in the code to describe how `Te0` is declared and the precise error message.

Comment: @fuz Good suggestion to add a minimal non-inline example. I've added one. (I still need to keep the C example because otherwise people will suggest things that don't work here, such as different instruction forms).

Comment: Have you tried putting all data into one table (e.g. by means of a `struct`) and then computing the offsets needed with the `offsetof` macro?

Comment: `Te0` has to be in the same section as your code, so that the compiler can compute the offset from one to the other. I'm not posting this as an answer, because I don't have the tools to check that it works; but try something like `const int Te0[256] __attribute__ ((section (".text"))) = { ... };`

Comment: @personal_cloud: Yes, you're expected to have the array's base address in a register.  So yes, other than these hacks, you will need more registers.  If you run out, then either you spill to the stack, or you regenerate values that were relatively cheap to get in the first place (like your registers).

Comment: @Nate "Relatively cheap" is relative. The 13-instruction sequence in the question repeats 2,560 times for each KB of data. It uses all available registers (the portion above is only 1 of 4 similar words). Expanding this to 17 instructions reduces performance significantly.

Comment: @TonyK, Yes, I am already using that method to put the tables at known addresses. But I was asking how to get the linker to keep the object code up to date with the symbols, as we normally expect it to do. And I was hoping to get rid of the linker section altogether, until Nate correctly pointed out that the ldr immediate is limited to 4KB.

Comment: @Nate OK so supposing the assembler doesn't support it directly... the assembler can emit labels. Can I pass an option to gcc to read in a list of labels and turn them into specific symbols? Maybe using regular expressions? (Granted, labels would clutter up the hex dumps. Maybe typing the addresses directly in the assembly is cleaner. I could use named constants like `#define _Te0 "0x200"` ... `"ldr %[z0], [%[z0], #"_Te0"] \n"`. As second best if the linker is unhelpful...)

Comment: It doesn't look from your source code as if you're "already using that method"!

Comment: If you're prepared to define your arrays at constant low addresses, then you can import those constants into your inline asm as an operand with the `i` constraint.  [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/M6nG4YcWh).  So at least that will allow you to have the address set at only one place in your code.

Comment: @Jester: Actually, there is [relocation type 35](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/espc0003/1-0) which yields the low 12 bits of a symbol.  There might be a way to use that.

Comment: @Nate re: the 4K limit. I just realized that ARMv6 has a [2-instruction sequence](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/writing-arm-assembly-language/load-immediate-values) to load any 32-bit constant. So this will often be useful to access tables that aren't in the bottom 4KB.

Comment: @personal_cloud: With `adr` you should be able to get the table's address into a register with one cheap ALU instruction, if it's within any reasonable distance of your code, which should be easy to arrange. Previously you were saying you couldn't afford even one instruction, but if you can, that should be better than `mov/movt`.

Comment: @Nate Well, yes, in the case of AES, I can't afford even one instruction, so absolute table addresses in the bottom 4K is the way to go for AES. In other cases, `adr` and/or `movt` is at least better than allocating a register. I need to read up on `adr` - thank you for the suggestion. (Does `adr` work with gcc inline assembly? It seems to reject the `%function` reference. And then I guess I have to put the function and the table in the same section so they're reasonably close? But I guess these are now separate questions)

Comment: @Nate Wow that Compiler Explorer website is really amazing.